# Need help identifying 6-pin SMD in Android TV box

Tags: voltage-regulator, identification, surface-mount

I somehow identified the problem in my Android TV box: I can see a short in a 6-pin SMD.

I am not an expert in fixing SMD. I am also unable to read the number written on the component (just a guess: *BC0C0* ; screenshot attached).

What SMD can we use here?

[image]

Comment: You can't really know if it's a short in the SMD until you remove the SMD and test it out of circuit. But maybe someone recognizes the company that came up with the code.

Comment: How did you determine there is a short, and even if there is, how do you know it is not intentional?

Comment: Tested with multimeter, continuity negative wire on any usb body and positive wire on 2R2 component (as in screenshot), there are 4 similar smds only 1 is beaping ..

Comment: I Refered this video to identify the short in smd.    https://youtu.be/vFw2YCirKuM

Comment: You don’t want an alternate, you want a ‘replacement’. How do you know if the smd is shorted or whether what is connected is shorted?  It looks like a buck converter chip, but as to which one that’s the challenge. It’s probably from a Chinese vendor which makes identification more challenging.